# 2-dimensional Fourier Transform of sine

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I'm asked to compute the two-dimensional Fourier Transform of the following function:

$$z = sin(ax+by)$$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

What I've tried is the following:

$$ \mathcal{FT} \{ sin(ax+by) \} = \int_{x \in X} \int_{ y \in Y} sin(ax+by)e^{-j2\pi f_x x} e^{-j2\pi f_y y} dx dy = \iint_{x,y} sin(ax+by)e^{-j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y} dx dy $$

Because $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$, we can merge the exponentials.

Since the sine can be separated as a sum of exponentials, i.e. $sin(x) = \frac{e^{jx}-e^{-jx}}{2j}$ and let us assume that $c = ax + by$; then:

$$... = \frac{1}{2j}\iint_{x,y} (e^{jc}-e^{-jc}) e^{-j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y} dx dy = \frac{1}{2j}\iint_{x,y} (e^{jc} e^{-j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y} - e^{-jc}e^{-j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y})dxdy =$$

$$= \frac{1}{2j}\iint_{x,y} (e^{jc -j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y} - e^{-jc -j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y})dxdy = \frac{1}{2j}\iint_{x,y} (e^{jc -j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y})dxdy - \frac{1}{2j}\iint_{x,y} e^{-jc -j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y})dxdy$$

Since a sum in a integral can be split into a sum of two integrals, as shown in the last step.

Now, I'm going to focus only on the first term, i.e. $\frac{1}{2j}\iint_{x,y} (e^{jc -j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y})dxdy$. First, let me develop the exponential with $c = ax + by$:

$$jc -j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y = j(ax + by) -j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y = $$

$$ = jax + jby - j2\pi f_x x -j2\pi f_y y = jx(a - 2 \pi f_x) + jy(b - 2 \pi f_y) = j2\pi x (\frac{a}{2\pi} - f_x) + j2\pi y (\frac{b}{2\pi} - f_y) $$

Therefore, we can now split the exponentials in the following manner:

$$ \frac{1}{2j}\iint_{x,y} e^{j2\pi x (\frac{a}{2\pi} - f_x) + j2\pi y (\frac{b}{2\pi} - f_y)}dxdy = \frac{1}{2j} \iint_{x,y} e^{j2\pi x (\frac{a}{2\pi} - f_x)} e^{j2\pi y (\frac{b}{2\pi} - f_y)}dxdy = \frac{1}{2j} \int_{x} e^{j2\pi x (\frac{a}{2\pi} - f_x)} dx \int_{y} e^{j2\pi y (\frac{b}{2\pi} - f_y)}dy$$

And given that we know that $ \mathcal{FT}\{ 1 \} = \int_{x} e^{-j 2 \pi f_0 x} dx = \delta (f_0)$, then:

$$ ... = \frac{1}{2j} \int_{x} e^{j2\pi x (\frac{a}{2\pi} - f_x)} dx \int_{y} e^{j2\pi y (\frac{b}{2\pi} - f_y)}dy = \frac{1}{2j} \delta ( f_x - \frac{a}{2\pi}) \delta ( f_y - \frac{b}{2\pi})$$

And I suppose that now I have to do the same thing for the second term. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: You are in the right direction. To simplify your calculations, forget about making a single exponential function. You can write $\sin(ax+by)$ in terms of $e^{jax}e^{jby}$ and the complex conjugate. Then group the $x$ terms in an exponential, and do the same for the $y$ terms. You will therefore skip some steps, to get to the same formula

Comment: @Andrei Are you sure? I calculated the second term and it gives me the same but negative. So, they cancel out and it gives me 0.